# write to csv file two lists separated by tab error

Tags: python, csv

I have to lists

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [[2,3,4,5],[2,4,3,9], [9,4,6,8], [7,3,8,5]]
```

I have written it to a csv file with delimiter as tab. Now I don't want to have the nested list as [2,3,4,5] but only the element 2,3,4,5. I don't know how to get rid of the the list brackets.

Here is my code:

```
with open('output.csv', 'w', encoding="ISO-8859-1", newline='') as myfile:
wr = csv.writer(myfile, delimiter='\t')
wr.writerows(zip(a,b))
```

output of my code:

```
1   [2, 3, 4, 5]
2   [2, 4, 3, 9]
3   [9, 4, 6, 8]
4   [7, 3, 8, 5]
```

But I want to have

```
1   2, 3, 4, 5
2   2, 4, 3, 9
3   9, 4, 6, 8
4   7, 3, 8, 5
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second column is the default `str()` of a list.  You can format the second column as a custom string to get what you want:

```py
import csv

a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [[2,3,4,5],[2,4,3,9], [9,4,6,8], [7,3,8,5]]

with open('output.csv', 'w', encoding="ISO-8859-1", newline='') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, delimiter='\t')
    for col1,col2 in zip(a, b):
        str_col2 = ', '.join([str(n) for n in col2])
        wr.writerow([col1, str_col2])
```

Output:

```
1       2, 3, 4, 5
2       2, 4, 3, 9
3       9, 4, 6, 8
4       7, 3, 8, 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're able to flatten an n-dimensional list with only `zip`. I'd do something like the following, to flatten every single output line of `zip(a, b)`:

```py
flattened = []
for ab in zip(a, b):
    flattened.append([ab[0]] + ab[1])

wr.writerows(flattened)
```